# Asterisk printed out as string when passing value to php script from bash

Tags: php, bash

So i have this part of code in the bash script.

```sh
uploadS()
{
file2=/home/somefile/somepath/$torrent_name/*.someextension
if [ checkif ]; then
php /patho/to/php/script/login.php someparam $somevar /home/somefile/$somevar $file2
#upload code
fi
}
```

The problem is that when i'm running this then i'm checking the `$argv` variables in php script and the file2 variable is passed with the asterisk so it's not - ho would i say - changing into the filename which i wanted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If it's passed with the `*`, it means there are no matching files. If there are several matching files, you'll get them all. If you want no files when there are no matches, use `shopt -s nullglob`. If you want an error when there are no matches, use `shopt -s failglob`.

Comment: That said, your design is a bit flawed here. You'll hit serious problems when you have filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path (and especially the `$torrent_name` part) is correct. If it is not, bash will not be able to expand the `*`.

Comment: Ok missed that. Corrected.